# where is sched.h located in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

I'm looking for the ached.h file on my Ubuntu server, but I can't find it. Online It said that it was in include/linux/sched.h but I don't have an include file / don't know where it is. Could someone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your computer find it using `find`. This is what it returned on my machine:

```
$ find / -name sched.h  2>/dev/null
/usr/include/sched.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/sched.h
/usr/include/linux/sched.h
```

Comment: For me on Ubuntu 19 `/usr/include/{,linux}/sched.h` is a very barebones header that does not include definitions I'd expect it to.  E.g. `find / -name sched.h  2>/dev/null|xargs grep -m1 task_struct` only returns `sched.h` headers in `/usr/src/linux-headers-*` but not in `/usr/include`.  Therefore I am getting the errors `p1.c:18:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘for_each_process’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     for_each_process(task) {
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
p1.c:18:27: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
     for_each_process(task) {`